# Failed to resolve: com.github.AnchorFreePartner.hydra-sdk-android:sdk:3.3.1

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever I tried to build the app I always get this:
Failed to resolve: com.github.AnchorFreePartner.hydra-sdk-android:openvpn:3.3.1
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
Anyone know who to solve this error.
I'm getting this error from last few days

Answer (score 0):

try:
com.github.AnchorFreePartner.hydra-sdk-android:openvpn:3.4:14